# Can I save this (hydrangea?) plant?

Tags: hydrangea

I have two of these rescued from a supermarket bin.

I assume the first thing to do is re-pot in something bigger. What's the prognosis? Can it be saved? Should I expect any positive results this summer? Should I prune it after re-potting? What care should I apply?

[image: Ragged looking plant. Possibly hydrangea.]

Answer (score 3):

It's not dead, it's just the flowers are fading. This will have been intended as a temporary visitor in the home as a houseplant, because *Hydrangea macrophylla* is not in flower at this time of year without being forced (assuming you're in the northern hemisphere) but it will grow outdoors.

Certainly give it a larger pot (with drainage holes) using new potting soil, cut off the spent flowers and their stems, water the plant well after potting on and let it recover and grow on. Keep it watered regularly when the surface of the soil feels just about dry to the touch - it will prefer a part shade situation outdoors. You might get flowers this year, but more likely next year, and it will be better off in the ground from end of next year.